# Woocommerce - How to put a product on a Wordpress portfolio page?

Tags: wordpress, product, woocommerce

Is there a way to put a link to a particular product from the Woocommerce store onto a Wordpress portfolio page?

I have a portfolio page that shows a picture of a room with a chair and a table. I want to put product links for the chair and table on the same portfolio page and have the product links connect to the product pages in the Woocommerce store. Ideally the product link would consist of a photo, the price, and the product name.

Is this possible? If so can anyone recommend a simple way to do this?

I am using the Forte theme from Pixedelic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way might be to use a shortcode from WooCommerce:
http://docs.woothemes.com/document/woocommerce-shortcodes/

Not sure if this will solve your problem exactly as desired, but it might get you close.